# How to have a variable inside javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, php

I have been searching an answer for like three days but still cannot find one that works.
I have this if statement in javascript block:

```
if (!(/@test.com\s*$/.test(document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value))) {
          alert("Please Enter Correct Email Domain"); 
            return false;
        }
```

I need to have this:
`var javaScriptVar = "<?php echo $ar[1]; ?>";`
to replace the test.com part in the if statement. Any idea how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pass a variable to a Regular Expression JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `RegExp` constructor instead of a literal (note that you need to escape backslashes when taking this approach):

```
var regex = new RegExp("@" + someVar + "\\s*$");
//                                      ^--- Notice the escaped backslash
```

Comment: I just try but always comes true no matter what I input: var regex = new RegExp("@" + javaScriptVar + "\\s*$"); 
if(!regex.test(document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value){
   alert("Please Enter Correct Email Domain"); 
            return false;
  }

Comment: For this testing, I have used var javaScriptVar = "test.com";